# How to change all url images in blogger with custom url images serving webp

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

Is there a a way to bulk change images in old blogposts into webp using Java or Jquery in blogger theme instead of going post by post?

Comment: it will be difficult to help you without showing some code (html/css/js)

Comment: somthing like that but another option than cdn.staticly.io/

    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      [...document.querySelectorAll("img[src^='https://bp1.blogspot.com']")].forEach(function(img) {
        let src = img.src;
        img.src = "https: //cdn.staticly.io/img/"+ src + "?format=webp";
      })
    })

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <img src="https://bp1.blogspot.com/image1.jpg" /><br/>
    <img src="https://bp2.blogspot.com/image2.jpg" /><br/>
    <img src="https://bp3.blogspot.com/image3.jpg" /><br/>